# Is it good to migrate my problem into MathOverflow?

Tags: support, mathoverflow

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158232/23875) is an elementary problem which seems difficult, and I'm not sure whether it could be solved out. A higher mathematics overlook might be needed.

Comment: MO is not a part of the SE network (it uses the SE platform in an old version, on a private server) so migration per se is impossible (which is why I removed the tag). Cross-posting might be reasonable after waiting for a few days - let your bounty expire first.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Another question is whether it is appropriate for MO. After the deadline of bounty, should I post a thread in meta.MO to ask whether it is appropriate?

Comment: If you are uncertain of this a thread on meta.MO is a reasonable approach. For this you do not need to wait for  the bounty period to end, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. I'm uncertain because it's an elementary problem, and the FAQ on MO says that *too elementary* problems are not welcomed.